# How can I get the position values of characters in a list?

Tags: c#

I've been trying for hours but seem unable to work this out, using C# I am trying to output the position (in the alphabet) of each character in a string entered by the user.

I have a list (not an array) holding this called alphabet:

```
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
```

I am then running a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    int value = alphabet.IndexOf(Convert.ToString(text[i]));
    textBox3.Text += (value);
}
```

Where alphabet is the list shown above, and text is the string input by the user. So it should be searching in `alphabet` for the position of the specific letter defined in `text[i]` right?

Instead, it just outputs value as `0` for every loop, any help?

Comment: Are you sure that text contains any one element from alphabet?

Comment: `textBox3.Text += (value);` doesn't compile. You should post the actual code that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My test app shows that your code actually works.  Are you sure the casing of the `text` var is as you expect?  Oddly, you'd be getting "-1"s in your textbox if the characters didn't exist in your list, it's as if you're sending a string of "aaaaaaaaaa" though as your `text` parameter.  Anyway, here's the proof:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> alphabet = new List<string>() {
            "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                int value = alphabet.IndexOf(Convert.ToString(text[i]));
                Console.Write(value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
0000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working just fine. Executing the following code - a slightly modified version of your code - assigns the value `19,4,18,19,18,19,17,8,13,6` to res.

```
var text = "teststring";

var alphabet = new List<string>() 
    { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
      "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
      "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

var res = "";

foreach (char c in text)
{
    int value = alphabet.IndexOf(c.ToString());
    res += (value) + ",";
}
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
var res = string.Join(",", text.Select(c => alphabet.IndexOf(c.ToString()).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var chars = new []
{
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
    'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
}.ToList();

var text = "hello";
var ids = text.Select(x => chars.IndexOf(x));
var result = string.Join(",", ids);
```

`result` would be "7,4,11,11,14"